# How to control Show/Hide fields at Runtime in Orbeon Form Runner?

Tags: forms, orbeon

I have created a form in orbeon form builder which has three 30 questions which are belongs to 3 categories. Now I don't want to show all the 30 questions to every one also I don't want to create different forms for each category because all these categories belongs to one module.

While adding the form I have a drop down question like "Select Category". If user select the first category then I need to display only first category related questions and hide the second and third category related questions.

Is there any way to achieve my task in Form Runner?

**UPDATE:**

@ebruchez, I have followed your suggestion, I tried testing this feature on default "contacts" form. I have created a new text field in the contact form named "Account Related Field" as a label and "control-10" as Control Name. Below is the screen shot for the same.

[image]

Then After that I clicked on control setting of the "Account Related Field" and under the "Formulas" tab I have added the following XPath expression in "Visibility" section. `$topic='Account'` following is the screenshot.

[image]

After adding the path expression I saved the contact form and published. Then I tried opening the form in form runner. But I am not able to view the  "Account Related Field" field on UI after selecting the "topic" value is "Account" in the form runner. This is the screenshot of form runner after publishing form in form builder.

[image]

Did I miss something. Please help to resolve the issue. I need to view "Account Related Field" field only if "topic" field value is "Account"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must use the dropdown *value*, not *label*. So `$topic = 'account'`. That works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, by using a "Visibility" formula under the section settings. For example if your dropdown is named `foo` and has two entries, `category1` and `category2`, then you can write:

```
$foo = 'category1'
```

to make the section visible only if the dropdown selected `category1`, and:

```
$foo = 'category2'
```

to make the section visible only if the dropdown selected `category2`.

This [doc](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Builder-~-Formulas) might help.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and some how I am not able to achieve my task. I have updated my question with screenshots. please tell me did I miss something?

Comment: I added a comment to the question above.